# Is BitcoinJS under active development?

Tags: bitcoind, development, javascript, bitcoinjs

I love the idea of a powerful alternative to bitcoind, and especially the ability to subscribe on blockchain events and easily process them on the server side.

However, I see the last activity on the [BitcoinJS](http://bitcoinjs.org/) code is 7-10 months ago.
Does anybody know the status of the BitcoinJS projects or can suggest alternatives?

**Update**: I'm now looking into [bitsofproof supernode](http://bitsofproof.com/), a project that looks really promising.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I just asked the same question in bitcoinjs google group: [https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/bitcoinjs](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/bitcoinjs)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think those guys started working on the Ripple project instead. They are skilled JS developers and they want to do something of their own with Ripple.

Comment: It seems like BitcoinJS had one major developer, [justmoon](https://github.com/justmoon). He's now contributing to the ripple client repository; I think that's accurate.