# Getting wallet balance with BitcoinJS + Bitcoin-lib (client lib)

Tags: client, bitcoinjs

I have server with BitcoinJS and Bitcoin ExitNode running. I try to fetch wallet balance from client with code from manual on wiki page. I have send money on client generated address, but app says that balance still 0 BTC. Please, see the code: http://jsfiddle.net/a6xfP/3/.

Comment: I asked a question regarding BitcoinJS a few days ago, kind of reluctant to use it as it seems development stopped 7 months ago.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, nivs.

Tell please, how you solved this problem? Is your issue is similar to mine?

Comment: @user4069 [This is the question he asked.](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/is-bitcoinjs-under-active-development)

Comment: I'm now looking into [bitsofproof supernode](http://bitsofproof.com/), a project that looks really promising.

Comment: thanx for answers